# PrimeFaces ManyCheckbox ArrayList not Updating inside modal dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectmanycheckbox, ajax-update

I have a modal dialog, where a user can select and deselect roles based on another user and then submit this to the database to be updated.

However, after debugging, the `ArrayList` that backs the `ManyCheckbox` doesn't get updated, and the `selectedRoles` `ArrayList` remains to what it originally was.

For example:

1. I load the application
2. There is one user in the database with role 'admin'
3. I try to edit this user and the dialog opens up, 'admin' checkbox is selected.
4. I click the 'user' role checkbox and click submit
5. The selectedRoles array is still only just 'admin' instead of 'admin' and 'user'

Here is my dialog modal:

```
<p:dialog header="Editing User ID: #{usersView.viewUser}" id="editUserDialog" widgetVar="editUserDialog" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:form id="editUserForm">
        <p:selectManyCheckbox id="roleSelect" value="#{usersView.selectedRoles}" layout="grid" columns="3">
            <f:selectItems value="#{rolesView.roles}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role.name}" itemValue="#{role.name}" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
        <p:separator />
        <p:commandButton process="@this" update=":form:tabs:adminView:userTable:userRoleOutput" value="Submit" id="EditUserSubmitButton" actionListener="#{usersView.editUserRole}" oncomplete="PF('editUserDialog').hide();" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

UserView:

```
@ManagedBean(name="usersView", eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped

private ArrayList<String> selectedRoles;

public Arraylist<String> getSelectedRoles()
{
    return this.selectedRoles;
}

public void setSelectedRoles(ArrayList<String> roles)
{
    this.selectedRoles = roles;
}

public void editUserRole(ActionEvent actionEvent)
{
    // This method literally just loops through all users and matches the one we're looking at
    User user = findUser();

    if (user != null)
    {
        // gives user checked roles in database and local session
        addSelectedRoles(user);

        ArrayList<String> rolesToRemove = user.getRoleNames();
        rolesToRemove.removeAll(selectedRoles);

        // removes user unchecked roles in database and local session
        removeSelectedRoles(user, rolesToRemove);
    }

    else
    {
        // Handle exception...
    }
}
```

I am working on a restricted VM, so I cannot copy and paste and this is all the information I can post, which I believe is enough.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BalusC my bad, stackoverflow always recommends it as a tag, I'll keep this in mind with future questions.

Comment: can you post your backing bean code

Comment: @Ankit I have posted this now, hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't chameleonize you question. And answers to one part should not be in the question and as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by removing `process="@this"` and now the ArrayList is getting updated.

`process="@this"` means that the current component of the commandLink and hence why it wasn't updating.